# How to make the corners of a button round?

Tags: android, android-button, rounded-corners

I want to make the corners of a `button` round. Is there an easy way to achieve this in Android?

Comment: check out this: http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/customize-button-in-android/

Comment: https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/ just set corner radius

Comment: this is not a broad question, its absolutely to the point. marking it as "too broad" is just a SO mentality which needs to be changed. Stop being dictators.

Comment: agree with user734028: what the heck how come closed for being too broad?? the only way this could have been more specific if the OP had asked how to set the corner radius to N pixels. Come on!

Comment: In the date of 2020, Google developed new UI Framework "JetPack Compose": It'is less code,intuitive,Accelerate Development and powerfull
I think it is alternative of "SwiftUI" [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose)

Answer (score 734, accepted):

If you want something like this

[image: Button preview]

here is the code.

1.Create a xml file in your drawable folder like mybutton.xml and paste the following markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />            
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
        </shape>
    </item>  
    <item >
       <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />            
       </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

2.Now use this drawable for the background of your view. If the view is button then something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Buttons" />
```

Comment: it crashed: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #24: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Comment: what creates the shadow on click? i am trying to reduce the shadow width at the bottom... no luck

Comment: I don't see what showing how selectors are coded has to do with explaining how button corners should be coded.

Comment: what is "android:state_focused" item for? I don't think that is relevant for mobile phones.

Comment: @Harsha , perhapse when you type in some text and there is the enter keybutton on keyboard layout. So you have to decide what Button view  to focus to be hit by default, Ok or Cancel or whatever . Otherwise  there is no need, seems

Answer (score 379):

Create a xml file in drawable folder like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
    <solid android:color="#ABABAB"/> 
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Apply this as background to button you want make corners round.

Or you can use separate radius for every corner like below

```
android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
android:topRightRadius="10dp"
```

Comment: You can just shorten the corners to android:radius="10dp", which will apply to all

Comment: This is not a complete solution as it does not support the various button states (pressed, focused, default). For a better solution see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334618/rounded-button-android

Comment: @BenSimpson, you will see that there is a difference in the shape when you put just that one line instead of defining each of the corner radii individually.

Answer (score 96):

> Is there an easy way to achieve this in Android?

With **Jetpack Compose** you can use the **`shape`** parameter:

```
    Button( 
        onClick = { /* Do something! */ },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ){
        Text("Button")
    }
```

[image]

---

With the [**Material Components library**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can use the [**`MaterialButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) with the **`app:cornerRadius`** attribute.

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:text="BUTTON"
        app:cornerRadius="8dp"
        ../>
```

[image]

It is enough to obtain a Button with rounded corners.

You can use one of Material button [styles](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#styles).
For example:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    .../>
```

[image]

Also starting from the version **1.1.0** you can also change the [shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) of your button. Just use the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute in the button style:

```
  <style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
  </style>
```

Then just use:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
   .../>
```

You can also apply the `shapeAppearanceOverlay` in the xml layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded"
   .../>
```

The `shapeAppearance` allows also to have different shape and dimension for each corner:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">32dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">32dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: It requires also to use Material theme

Comment: @Vlad Yes, material components requires a material theme.

Answer (score 52):

Create an XML file like below one. Set it as background for the button. Change the radius attribute to your wish, if you need more curve for the button.

**button_background.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/primary" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**Set background to your button:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>
```

Answer (score 34):

create shape.xml in drawable folder

like shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <stroke android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
  <gradient 
    android:angle="225"
    android:startColor="#DD2ECCFA"
    android:endColor="#DD000000"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
   android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

and in myactivity.xml

you can use

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Shap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Shape"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```

Answer (score 17):

Create file myButton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorButton"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

add to your button

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/myButton"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

Simple way i found out was to make a new xml file in the drawable folder and then point the buttons background to that xml file. heres the code i used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#ff8100"/>
<corners android:radius="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: To restore the Material-theme ripple effect in the custom drawable background, add `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` in the Button View. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327188/android-setting-background-color-of-button-loses-ripple-effect

Answer (score 11):

Create rounded_btn.xml file in Drawable folder...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
     <solid android:color="@color/#FFFFFF"/>    

     <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/#000000"
        />

     <padding android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"
         /> 

     <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dip" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip" 
         android:topLeftRadius="5dip" android:topRightRadius="5dip"/> 
  </shape>
```

and use this.xml file as a button background

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_btn"
android:text="Test" />
```

Answer (score 9):

style button with icon
[image]

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonVisaProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:onClick="visaProgress"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_1468863158_double_loop"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Visa Progress"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

shape.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="14dp" />
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerColor="#1FA8D1"
    android:centerX="35%"
    android:endColor="#060d96"
    android:startColor="#0e7e1d"
    android:type="linear" />
<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 9):

**New method from material design**

all you will need is this attribute **cornerRadius**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorReviewSelected"
    android:text="click me"/>
```

---

---

**Old method**

Drawable Folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#999999"/>
</shape>
```

Layout Folder

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    <!-- add style to avoid square background -->
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:background="@drawable/corner_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

**Make sure to add style to avoid square background**

Answer (score 8):

This link has all the information you need.
[Here](https://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/customize-button-in-android/)

Shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid   android:color="#EAEAEA"/>

    <corners    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
                android:topRightRadius="8dip"
                android:topLeftRadius="1dip"
                android:bottomRightRadius="1dip"
                />
</shape>
```

and main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello Android from NetBeans"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nishant Nair"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

This should give you your desired result.

Best of luck

Answer (score 8):

#### If you want change corner radius as well as want a ripple effect in button when pressed use this:-

1. Put **button_background.xml** in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#F7941D">

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#F7941D" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

2. Apply this background to your button

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:id="@+id/myBtn"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Button" />
```

Comment: Not only is this much simpler than the accepted anwer, but the ripple effect provides much clearer UX.

Answer (score 6):

There is a `app:cornerRadius` attribute for the normal `Button` tag.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="#009688"
    android:onClick="xyz"
    android:paddingHorizontal="64dp"
    android:text="@string/login"
    app:cornerRadius="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/passwordCustom"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" 
    />
```

Comment: This works!! Take my vote

Answer (score 4):

if you are using vector drawables, then you simply need to specify a <corners> element in your drawable definition. I have covered this in a [blog post](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/55).

If you are using bitmap / 9-patch drawables then you'll need to create the corners with transparency in the bitmap image.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple CardView. You can make the corner of your Button round. You can set the corner radius of the Card and use other features of the Card such as elevation.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:cornerRadius="32dp"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the card layout like below

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Template"

                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: bad idea ever.  because the question is about rounded button

Answer (score 0):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn2jL.png)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/add_coment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/blue_shadow_outline"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/coment"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/coment">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_style2"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ar1"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:text="text "
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="17dp" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think it's proper solution. for visualize interface this is ok . but functionally both are not same.

Answer (score 0):

create XML file in drawable and set button background to this file.

XML file code for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--|^@^|_[ Shadows ]_|^@^|-->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" />
            <gradient android:angle="315" android:startColor="#c2c2c2" android:endColor="#c0c0c0"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!--|^@^|_[ Background ]_|^@^|-->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient android:angle="135" android:startColor="#f7f7f7" android:endColor="#fbfcfc"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use this attribute:

```
app:cornerRadius="radius"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this attribute:**

```
app:cornerRadius=""
```

Like

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?