# Creating such a Button with Android? (Inspired by iOS)

Tags: android, button, styles, xamarin.android

On an iOS App I saw such a Button:

[image]

The same I would like to do in Android, how could I achieve this?
What I tried is the following code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/widget41"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Email1 testmail@gmail.com"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Looks something like that:

[image]

Well just a normal (ugly looking) Button. I have no idea, how I could style it like in iOS. Any suggestions or links would be appreciated!

Comment: I have no experience in iOS App development, so maybe u know what it is for Android?

Comment: A bit of googling gave me this; http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Recipes/Resources/General/Style_a_Button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution would be to create your own custom view that behaves like the iOS counterpart (though, as other users have mentioned, Android does have it's own design guidelines, and the view that you are seeing is an iOS implementation that is designed for that platform).

[image]

If you look at the iOS image above (a copy of yours with some parts highlighted), I have split it up into sections.

You could use an Android `ViewGroup` like a `LinearLayout` to create the overall image, and give the `LinearLayout` a border or background (which can be a bitmap image of a rounded rectangle for example (See **Android Nine Patch** for an example of how to make this fit multiple screens).

1. Firstly, for the mail icon you would need a `LeftAligned ImageView` 
   with appropriate dimensions.
2. Next up we have a `Bold TextView` containing the text "Email1".
3. This is followed by another `TextView` which is blue and uses the
   `elipsize` property (as defined in an Android XML layout) to create
   `"..."` at the end once the text has reached the max width it can
   consume. (Use `android:ellipsize="end"` in the XML)
4. Finally we have an indicator image, which again can be an `ImageView`
   sized appropriately.

You could also achieve this with a `RelativeLayout`, which would allow you to `RightAlign` the indicator image, `LeftAlign` the mail icon, and allow the text to fill the space in between that it can get hold of.

Example of Nine Patch use for the background [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is `UITableView` in iOS(just like `ListView` in android). It depends on the list item design you do it. There is no such `Button` Control in Android.

Comment: There is no such Button Control in Android? really

Comment: you have to design it as it look like of iOS but there is no direct control

Answer (score 0):

You should design your own button to looks like iOS one.

Android has it own design guidelines:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, as others have clearly mentioned there is no default Button in Android like this, and for your info neither is in iOS. Its all about the design. Anything is possible, in the end it all comes to how far are you willing to go to achieve it.

Below is a simple code, that will be close to your design.

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_background"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/envelope"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/email" />
```

There can be other ways also, like that whole view could be a ViewGroup, either a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` and there could be multiple `TextView`s and `ImageView`s inside that.

Comment: thx for the answer, anyway, I got errormessages, that there is no resource found for the 3 `@drawables/..` and the other thing is that it should be a control or something else, where I can attach a Clickevent

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://appfulcrum.com/2010/08/08/how-to-create-rounded-corner-buttons-for-android/) is a tutorial for creating stylized android buttons.  You can round the corners and change the background colors to look like the buttons in ios.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6054562/771999) is a similar question.

Hope this helps.