# How do I round a button programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I have a `Button` which populates a `GridView` using a custom adapter's call to `getView()`. As such, there is no .xml file for the `Button`.

Is there a way to programmatically round the `Button`?

Comment: Why does using an adapter suggest you can't have an XML layout? Also, I have no idea what you're asking. You want to draw a round button?

Comment: It doesn't mean I can't - but I don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a nine patch, here is an example one:

[image]

save this in your `/res/drawable-mdpi/` directory with the filename `btn_round.9.png`

then in your java code do this:

```
mBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_round);
```

because it is 9 patch wit will stretch to fit whatever content you are putting inside the button. Search for "android draw9patch" to learn more about how to create the 9 patch files.

Answer (score 2):

Below given method returns rounded bitmap of image.Apply it to button image and check if this can help

```
public Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
            .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML drawable background with corners and use setBackground.  See [How to make the corners of a button round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round)

You can use this even though the button itself isn't defined in xml, you're just declaring the background as an xml file.