# Android, how can I implement rounded corners for ImageButton and then change the color programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-styles, android-imagebutton

I have `ImageButton` on the layout of my application and I want to have rounded corners for this `ImageButton`, so I'm using style like:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</shape>
```

and then I'm using `android:background="@drawable/my_rounded_shape.xml"/>`

The problem is that after this I want to change background color from black to some custom color, but I can't modify style programmatically and there is no way to generate new style with corners but with different color and apply to my `ImageButton`.

Could you clarify is there any way to do it or any workaround?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194522/how-do-i-round-a-button-programmatically-in-android this looks a lot like your question

Answer (score 0):

Try it:
Create another XML Shape With Name For Example "SS"
and with your new properties

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@android:color/red" />
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
<solid android:color="@android:color/blue"/>
```

After then

```
Button b = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.button1));
    b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ss));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this approach doesn't allow actually to change color dynamically (that's what I need)

Answer (score 0):

After some time I came up with solution for my case - in my Java code I do something like:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) imageButton.getBackground();
drawable.setColor(color);
```

This allows me to save rounded corners described in my "shape" and change background color at the same time.