# Customize corner button android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

I have issues when design button in android. How can I make button like same the picture below

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the corners of a button round](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round)

Comment: Thank you. I try set radius but it's not like same under ! ! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one file named yourfilename.xml in your drawable folder and put below code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp">
</corners>

<stroke android:color="#FFFFFF"
    android:width="1dp"></stroke>
</shape>
```

In your main.xml file put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FBBECB">

<Button
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:background="@drawable/yourfilename" 
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="54dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

that's it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to make custom file in your drawable folder..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <corners
   android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
   android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
   android:topRightRadius="8dp">
```

```
<stroke android:color="#FFFFFF"
 android:width="1dp"></stroke>
</shape>
```

And then use it in your xml file file for button

Like:

```
android:background="@drawable/customfile" // get from drawable folder
```