# how to round corners of a Button but keep its default appearance

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a Button that looks according to the `Theme.Holo.Light`. I used to round its corners by setting its background to the following:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:shape="rectangle" >

   <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
   </shape>
```

Now the `Button` becomes transparent. I tried to create a selector, add a `solid` attribute and use 2 of such `drawables` for normal and pressed states, but I could not copy the default `Button` behavior of the `Holo.Light` theme. So I'm looking for 2 possible solutions: either somehow round the Button's corners without affecting its default Style or find the XML defining the mentioned style so I can copy it. I've been looking inside the SDK and using this reference: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml  but did not succeed.

Any ideas how to make a rounded corners `Button` BUT keep all the other appearance attributes to their defaults?

Comment: Maybe using some 9 patches would help.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo why? I don't need any custom backgrounds, I only need to round the corners of the button and keep all other things to their defaults

Comment: The same reason why you tried using an xml drawable: to get round corners.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo I can round its corners, but the default background gets lots then. Using a 9 patch would result in exactly the same

Comment: NO. A 9 patch doesn't have to be transparent. The original **style** (not theme, as erroneously linked in your question) uses 9 patches. If you read [THIS](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) document and search for btn_default (beginning at line 1552), you will learn how to **make a style that overrides the standard drawables (9 patches)**. Then it's just a matter of copying the original artworks to your app's drawable folders and round their corners.

Comment: Begin from line 1995 (instead of 1552), to see the **light** variant.

Comment: ah ok, I have found the source for `btn_default_holo_light.xml` on GitHub, but I need to copy it into my project (so I can modify it) since that resource is not public and I can't reference it. Any idea where inside the SDK I can find that?

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/18879660/2337837

Comment: If you're using Windows, it's here: **C:\Your_Path_To_Eclipse\sdk\platforms\android-XY\data\res\drawable**, where XY is 11 to 19 (depending on you minSdkVersion)

Comment: thx I found it, you can post your suggestions as an answer

Comment: Yep, done! I tried to make it flow a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original style uses 9 patches.
If you read [THIS](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) document and search for btn_default (beginning at line 1995), you will learn how to make a style that overrides the standard drawables (9 patches).
Then it's just a matter of copying the original artworks to your app's drawable folders and round their corners.

They'll be referred in a StateList drawable, called **btn_default_holo_light.xml**

If you're using Windows, it's here: **C:\Your_Path_To_Eclipse\sdk\platforms\android-XY\data\res\drawable**, where XY is 11 to 19 (depending on you minSdkVersion)

And the 9 patches here: **C:\Your_Path_To_Eclipse\sdk\platforms\android-XY\data\res\drawable-RES**, where XY is 11 to 19 (depending on you minSdkVersion) and RES is the specific dpi resolution (mdpi, as a reference)