# xml file in drawable which is usable for all resolutions

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm very very new to this whole android development thing, I'm trying to create a button with rounded corners and found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round) about it.

They mention I should put a button.xml in my drawable folder. The problem is that I have 5 of them(hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi). Is there a way to use one button.xml for all those drawable folders?

Comment: create just drawable folder and put it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a new subfolder of `res` and name it `drawable`. Put the xml there. You can use this folder for drawables that are the same for any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to use only one size of button. These folders are there for different screen sizes. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html).

As explained in Iconography you should use the 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio.