# Android : Add radius to imageButton programmatically

Tags: android

How can i add radius to imageButton object programmatically?
I checked exist topic on this site but i could not found my answer?
I want to add radius without xml file

Comment: Do you mean to add a **rounded corner**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round check this . This may help you :)

Comment: Thanks, but i want to add it programmatically without xml

Comment: There are several **easy** ways to do that. One involves using a ShapeDrawable (xml). Another one involves using a 9 patch (png). Then there are the **hard** ways to do that... programmatically. See Roman Guy's post: http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using GradientDrawable.

```
 GradientDrawable shape =  new GradientDrawable();
 shape.setCornerRadius(8);

 ImageButton ivButton = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.ivbtn );
 ivButton.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
```

Enjoy!!!

Comment: But when i calling setBackground on object , my previous details lost

Comment: Use setBackgroundDrawable instead of setBackground.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `GradientDrawable`.

here is an example :

```
GradientDrawable gdDefault = new GradientDrawable();
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(0xFFFF6666);
gdDefault.setColor(bgColor);
gdDefault.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
gdDefault.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
yourView.setBackgroundDrawable(cd);
```

Comment: How can i get button previous attributes and appear them again in this solution?
Like background,color and etc..

Comment: I think you can just `setCornerRadius` and don't use other methods in my example and then you don't need previous attributes ;)

Comment: I used just setCornerRadius ,but my previous background attribute in xml layout missed with this code

Comment: <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/my_location_button"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#99000000"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_gps_off" />

Comment: if your background was `transparent` it should be ok but if you are setting custom background to your view, use `gdDefault.setBackgroundDrawable(view.getBackgroundDrawable());`

Comment: I've just edited my answer for your use. see it again :)