# how to change color of custom state button programmatically

Tags: android

considering  [How to make the corners of a button round](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18879660/3138818)
how to change background color programmatically ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="3dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
     <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />            
 </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="3dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
     <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
 </shape>
  </item>  
<item >
<shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="3dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
     <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />            
 </shape>
 </item>
 </selector>
```

Comment: why not , i want change start color and end color According to user select color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do like,

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFAA0000));
```

Comment: set default button color to black and :  
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFAA0000, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);

Answer (score 0):

**You can set a background resource to a button by `setBackgroundResource` method..**

Suppose your button is `bt` and your xml drawable file is `button_bg.xml`, then you can set the background of button `bt` to the drawable resource `button_bg.xml` programmatically as shown below :

```
bt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg);
```

**Now whenever you want to set the start and end colors of the layout you want, do the following** **:**

```
View layout_bt = findViewById(R.id.layout_main);//Your layout consisting of the button bt

GradientDrawable drawable_grad = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
        new int[] {<start_color_here>,<end_color_here>}); //Set the start and end colors here
drawable_grad.setCornerRadius(0f);

layout_bt.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable_grad);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but how to change button color in button_bg.xml

Comment: Updated my answer, please check again!

Comment: Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. in layout_bt.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable_grad);

Comment: Please try **setBackgroundResource** instead

Comment: Thanks , but setBackgroundResource need input id(int)