# How to make button like this in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to implement button in android with following layout.How to make it??

[image]

i have already implemented button like this

[image]

i used following code to make

```
<TextView
              android:id="@+id/action_text_share"
                            style="@style/mediumTextSize"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:singleLine="false"
                            android:text="Share by Text"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                             android:background="@drawable/white_broder_round_with_transparent_bg"
                            android:textColor="@color/blackColor" />
```

and have drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/removeContactRedColor"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="@color/removeContactRedColor" />
    <corners 
       android:radius="5dip"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: I really do not understand the question. If you've already made a button that looks the same, but just needs different text, surely you can make the next one?

Comment: Maybe you want make the corners of a button round. Please check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round

Comment: What you have tried so far? can you please show us your code?

Comment: set background image with text this is simple formate else hard to manage it will not manage by style code or this can not manage by style

Comment: you can write a drawable xml with what you want and set the background for the button

Comment: i want to add dis-continuous  white border instead of full white border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this in drawable, `<item android:right="-2dp">` will remove stroke from the right end.

```
 <item android:right="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/app_white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Create a drawable image of the background and use this one as background.
2. Assuming you created this with xml, create a solid blue shape and place it over the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Design a Background Image and Set it to Button with correct Padding and Margin

[image]

Set Text with The Background of Similar Above Image according to your Need