# How to draw a ellipse for imageButton xamarin.android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

The default style of a `ImageButton` is square.

```cs
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgNextPlayer"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:tint="#757575" />
```

Comment: Oh boy, I already told you: please use `<!-- language: c# -->` for formatting and not code snippet. **That's C# and not HTML!**

Comment: Calling that C# is a stretch.  Yes, xamarin is mainly a C# platform, but this is an android xml resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried creating a shape in the drawable folder `mybuttonshape.xml`:

like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/> 
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

then setting the background of your button to this drawable:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgNextPlayer"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybuttonshape"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
```

check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6054562/1107580) for other options

Answer (score 2):

You would set your `android:background="@android:....` to be a drawable:

```
android:background="@drawable/myellipsebutton"
```

Then add a drawable called `myellipsebutton.xml`:

- Resource/Drawable/myellipsebutton.xml

In this [drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html), you can define the shape of the button, in this case I'm using `oval` instead of `rectangle`, `line` and `ring` are also available:

---

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:startColor="#F44336" android:endColor="#E57373" android:angle="270" />
            <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#607D8B" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:startColor="#3F51B5" android:endColor="#9FA8DA" android:angle="270" />
            <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#607D8B" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:startColor="#2196F3" android:endColor="#BBDEFB" android:angle="270" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#607D8B" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

---

[image]