# how to fix the button from rectangle to rounded rectangle?

Tags: android, button

I can find many rounded-rectangle button but it is not working to me.

What do I miss?

It is `layout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#ebf1ff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/wrapperWidthWeightSumOne"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTypeAll"
            style="@style/ConsentTypeBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:text="All"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   (...)

</LinearLayout>
```

This is button's style:

```
<style name="ConsentTypeBtn">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">onClick</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_btn_consent_all</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

...and this is `selector_btn_consent_all.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/consent_type_on">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#1F3259"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/consent_type_on"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/consent_type_off"></item>
```

Comment: instead of `radius` try giving each corner radius

Comment: Always write the links of the solutions which didn't work.

Comment: Does this one work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `selector_btn_consent_all.xml` has status like this: when `android:state_selected="true"`, use `android:drawable="@drawable/consent_type_on"`.

So, find `consent_type_on.xml` at your `drawable` folder, and it would be `rectangle`, add `<corners android:radius="4dp" />`

EDIT

then, make `consent_type_on.xml` at your `drawable` folder. example here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

</shape>
```

Comment: consent_type_on is just hex of Color... in colors.xml

Comment: check changes. if you want to change color of drawable's background(=solid), modify that `@android:color/holo_blue_bright` to your color hex code, or `@color/consent_type_on`