# How I can do a button with left/right side as rounded as circle

Tags: android, rounded-corners, aspect-ratio, screen-size

I'm trying to do a button with the sides rounded, but when I change the size of screen the button sides left to be rounded as circles, doesn't mantain the aspect ratio (I think).

I want to have the next togglebutton in everysize. How I can do an XML with the sides rounded for every resolution?

[image: ToogleButton Rounded Sides as Circles]

I've read this, but is not a solution ([How to make the corners of a button round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round))

Comment: check my ans...

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct... almost:
if you will set corners to some value (let's say 20dp), but your button height will be greater (like 40dp) - you will end with rounded corners instead of rounded sides. The solution is thus straightforward: set `android:corners` attribute to some high enough value that will be greater than button height:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="200dp" />
    <size
        android:height="16dp"
        android:width="32dp" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable resource file in xml. The following is code for a blue button

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#2196f3"></solid>

    <corners android:radius="12dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

Then just asign this resource file as the background to one of your textViews

I hope this helps

Comment: If I have a big big screen with that values it possible that the button won't be completely rounded in the sides.

Comment: Just alter the radius of the corners to a smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="#1ee" />
</shape>
```

Comment: thanks but is the same problem that I've explained below in other answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.