# I want to draw rectangular shape with slightly rounded sides but not rounded corners in android?

Tags: android

[image]

I want to draw this shape in xml not through coding, rectangle with circular sides not rounded corner

Comment: Try  <corners android:radius="0" />

Comment: rectangle with circular side, ellipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6054562/7874047

Comment: no, you cannot do that in xnl

Comment: How to do it in coding?

Answer (score 0):

Create a button like this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background" />
```

Add this code inside background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/dark_grey" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```