# ImageButton with rounded corner using xml only?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, rounded-corners

I'm trying to make a ImageButton like this

[image: this is the type of button I'm trying to replicate]

however, I can't seem to find a way to do it using xml only. I tried custom libraries, they don't seem to work perfectly. is there no other way? what can I do instead of using ImageButton?

Comment: there is a lot of text on that button. I think you should use some layout, and place all the views inside it, and then set it's background to the one with rounded corners, and add a click listener to it

Comment: Well I don't exactly want that, I want an image to be in that shape. I'll have hard-coded info directly on the image using photoshop.

Comment: So, if the balance changes, you have another hardcoded text on the image? What makes you think Photoshop and Image is the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cardview with card corner radius

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"/>
```

And add imagebutton inside cardview

Comment: @Shashank Shetty you can try this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an xml code.

1.Create a xml file in your drawable folder like button.xml and paste the following markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />            
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
        </shape>
    </item>  
    <item >
       <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />            
       </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

2.Now use this drawable for the background of your view. If the view is button then something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Buttons" />
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round)

Comment: But my requirement is to add an image as background, how do I do that?

Comment: You can use the ImageButton to replace the Button

Answer (score 0):

Create an XML file inside drawable.

```
<shape
      android:shape="rectangle"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners
            android:radius="28dp"
    />

    <solid
        android:color="#00BADE"
/>
</shape>
```

and then inside your **imageButton** or whatever.

```
    android:background="@drawable/buttonShape"
```