# Single xml for multiple buttons with similar style

Tags: android-studio

I want to make 3 similar buttons, the difference between them is that they are different colors. I had found out earlier that the way to give the buttons rounded corners is through creating an xml file for it, but in that case I had added the color for the button into the xml file. In this case I don't want to do that, since then I would have to make 3 virtually identical xml files to change the color for each button. Is there a way to split the code to have all three buttons reference a single xml for the button style, and have a separate line of code to just modify the color?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `values` folder of your project, create a `styles.xml` file (if it doesn't already exist). Then, add code similar to below to set the common features that you want each button to have:

```
<!-- Style for a button -->
<style name="buttonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Then, in your layout file, reference this style that you just created in all three of your buttons similar to the following:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/restore_button"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/restore_button_text" />
```

Then, change the color of each button individually with the following code in each button layout:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

Finally, if you want to also create a button with rounded corners, reference this StackOverflow post for directions:
[How to make the corners of a button round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round)
You will need to create a custom layout and reference it within each button as a Drawable.

Comment: Is there a way to split the color and rounded corners? In your answer you had color as a background, and in the post you referenced also had rounded corners as a background, and I thought you can’t have 2 backgrounds. I’d rather not make three different xml just to change the color.

Comment: Take a look at Sandip Jadhav’s answer on that same link. It appears that a simpler way to create rounded corners would be to add this to your button layout: android:radius="10dp".